# How to know when a PDF is rendered using PDFKit

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I'm trying to show a loading while a PDF ins't already been shown on the screen. The problem is, my loading always stops before the document is already rendered, sometimes it can't take 2 or 3 seconds and I need to know when the PDF is already rendered to stop the activyIndicator. IS IT possible using PDFKIT? My code:

```
class PDFViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
    var pdfDocument: PDFDocument!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupPDFView()
        setupNavigationBar()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.startLoading()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        loadPDF()
    }

    private func loadPDF() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let url = URL(string: self.viewModel.pdfURL) else {
                self.showAlert(with: self.viewModel.strings.invalidInvoice)
                return
            }

            let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())

            let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
            downloadTask.resume()
        }
    }

    private func setupPDFView() {
        self.pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        self.pdfView.autoScales = true
    }

    func startLoading() {

        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
            !window.subviews.contains(where: { $0 is LoadingView }) else { return }

        let loadingView = LoadingView(frame: window.bounds)
        window.addSubview(loadingView)

        Thread.performUIUpdate {
            loadingView.startAnimation()
        }
    }

    func stopLoading() {

        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
        let view = window.subviews.first(where: { $0 is LoadingView }),
        let loadingView = view as? LoadingView  else { return }

        Thread.performUIUpdate {
            loadingView.stopAnimation()
            loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: location)

            if let pdfDocument = self.pdfDocument {
                self.pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            }

            self?.stopLoading()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code that is incomplete. If `self.startLoading()` is relevant, _show_ the definition of `startLoading`. Don't leave us to guess what it does.

Comment: my bad. I just added the code

Comment: Okay, I see. So where exactly is the 2 or 3 second delay? (I'm a little surprised your code works at all, because you are not picking up the downloaded document fast enough, but that might be a different issue.)

Comment: right now i'm using urlSession to stop the loadingView. When I call self?.stopLoading the PDF is already downloaded and the pdfView.document is already set. But I call the stopLoading, the loading stops... and the pdf ins't displaying on the screen yet. Sometimes it takes 2 or 3 seconds to actually displays, sometimes it displays exactly when stopLoading is called. Btw, i forgot to add stopLoading definition, i'm adding, but it basically stops the loading view.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a really bad idea:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: location)
```

The problem is that while you are getting off the current thread and the asynchronous code starts, the method finishes and the temporary document at `location` can be destroyed. I would suggest writing like this:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    let pdf = PDFDocument(url: location)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.pdfDocument = pdf
```

I'm not saying that that will solve your issue, but it seems a lot less dangerous than what you're doing.

As for your actual issue, I would suggest registering for a notification such as [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1503832-pdfviewdocumentchanged) and see whether it arrives at the right moment.

Answer (score 2):

You have to observe the PDFViewVisiblePagesChanged notification to know when a PDFView pages are visible, add your code in the method.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pdfViewVisiblePagesChanged(sender:)), name: .PDFViewVisiblePagesChanged, object: nil)

@objc func pdfViewVisiblePagesChanged(sender: Notification) {

    //Add your code here
}
```