# How to know when PDF document is downloaded in PDFKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building a really simple app, which displays PDF documents. However, how to know when PDF document is rendered?

Here's how my app looks like:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Now, I have a ProgressView which shows while the document is being downloaded. How do I hide the ProgressView when the document is downloaded and begins to render? I'm doing all of this in SwiftUI, I connected the PDFKit using UIKit in a SwiftUI app. Now, how do I. do it? I found this, but this applies only to UIKit: [How to know when a PDF is rendered using PDFKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603064/how-to-know-when-a-pdf-is-rendered-using-pdfkit)

### My code:

#### PDFRepresentedView:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct PDFRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    
    let url: URL
    let singlePage: Bool
    
    init(_ url: URL, singlePage: Bool = false) {
        self.url = url
        self.singlePage = singlePage
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFRepresentedView>) -> UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        if singlePage {
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        }
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFRepresentedView>) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    }
}
```

#### PDFReaderView:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PDFReaderView: View {
    
    var url: URL
    
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView("pdf.downloading")
    }

}

struct PDFReaderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PDFReaderView(url: URL(string: "https://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU19600300168/U/D19600168Lj.pdf")!)
    }
}
```

#### HomeView:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("needsAppOnboarding") private var needsAppOnboarding: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List(deeds) { deed in
                    NavigationLink(destination: PDFReaderView(url: deed.url)) {
                            Text(deed.name)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("title")
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: $needsAppOnboarding) {
                OnboardingView()
            }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a better option than letting `PDFDocument` do the loading from the URL would be to load the data yourself. Then, you can respond appropriately to errors, etc.

```
import PDFKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataLoader : ObservableObject {
    @Published var data : Data?
    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func loadUrl(url: URL) {
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { $0.data }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let failureType):
                    print(failureType)
                    //handle potential errors here
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
        }, receiveValue: { (data) in
            self.data = data
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var dataLoader = DataLoader()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let data = dataLoader.data {
                PDFRepresentedView(data: data)
            } else {
                Text("Loading")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            dataLoader.loadUrl(url: URL(string: "https://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU19600300168/U/D19600168Lj.pdf")!)
        }
    }
}

struct PDFRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    
    let data: Data
    let singlePage: Bool = false
    
    func makeUIView(context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFRepresentedView>) -> UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        if singlePage {
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        }
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFRepresentedView>) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
    }
}
```

In this example, `DataLoader` is responsible for getting the `Data` from the URL. Note the comment I've left in about where you might respond to errors.

Back in the main view, "Loading" is displayed unless there's `Data` available, in which case `PDFRepresentedView` is now shown, which now takes a `Data` object instead of a `URL`.